# Why all the code works except the for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a code, all the code is workin except the for-loop

```
let query = args.slice(1).join(' ');

client.database.query(`SELECT * FROM centres WHERE name="${query}"`, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (!results[0]) {
        message.channel.send(msg.cs.notExist)
    } else {
        client.database.query(`SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE centre="${query}"`, function (err, res, field) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res.length)
            let i;
            for (i = 0; i === res.length; i++) {
                message.channel.send(res[i].name)
                console.log(i)
            }
            /*   message.channel.send(`${msg.cs.stats}${query}

            ${msg.abreviation.cdc}${client.functions.username(client, results[0].cdc)}
            ${msg.abreviation.cdca}${client.functions.username(client, results[0].cdca)}
            ${msg.cs.vehicule} ${results[0].vehicules}`)*/
        })
    }
});
```

I just have 4 in output for res.length

Comment: Nice SQL injection. Apart from that, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Voted to close on the basis it's a typographical error. `i === res.length` should be `i < res.length` or `i <= res.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=0; i===res.length; i++
```

The condition in the for loop is contradicting. Initially `i` is 0 and the condition for the loop is given such that `i` is always equal to `res.length`, then after each iteration `i++` will increment `i`. Suppose the length of res is 7. Due to that condition the loop will never run to begin with because `i` is 0. If `i<res.length` was the condition then it will work fine.The loop will look like

```
for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, you should use <= or < inside loop

```
for(i=0; i <= res.length; i++){
  message.channel.send(res[i].name)
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i = 0 initially while res.length = 4. The loop terminates immediately. Change it to i < res.length